# Getting NullPointerException while passing value using sendkey in POM

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, cucumber-java

[contact us steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2b2M.png)

[contact us page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esa4C.png)

[base page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIMak.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8njYx.png)

console:
null

```
      java.lang.AssertionError: Unable to send keys to webelement,Exception:null
          at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:97)
     at pageObjects.BasePage.sendkeystoWebelemnt(BasePage.java:27)
                  at pageObjects.ContactUs_Page.enterFirstname(ContactUs_Page.java:43)
    at CucumberFramework.contactUsSteps.user_enter_a_vliad_first_name(contactUsSteps.java:38)
```

Answer (score 0):

Its the web element, textfield_Firstname that is null here.

Because you haven't initiated the web-elements.

Before you call any method in a webpage, you have to initiate them.

If the web-page name is 'ContactUs_Page';

```
PageFactory.initElements(driver, ContactUs_Page.class);
```

Therefore in your contactUsSteps class,

In user_enter_a_vliad_firstname() method, before you call the enterFirstName("test") method you have to initiate web elements.

```
    PageFactory.initElements(getDriver(), ContactUs_Page.class);
    ContactUs_Page.enterFirstName("test");
```